# Wrong result in CUDA 6.0

Tags: cuda

I am writing a sample program in CUDA 6.0 C/C++. The program can recognize the device, but there seem to be an error during the running time: the result array's elements all are equals to 0 with no reasons.
(My GPU: Geforce EN9400GT ASUS)
This is my code

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <malloc.h>
     #include <cuda_runtime.h>
     #define    SIZE 1024

     __global__ void VectorAdd(int* a, int* b, int* c, int n)
     {
        int i = threadIdx.x;

    if (i < n) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}

void printResult(int* ar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, ar[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int *a, *b, *c;
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
    int device, count;
    cudaDeviceProp* prop = (cudaDeviceProp*)malloc(sizeof(cudaDeviceProp));

    int GPUavail = cudaGetDeviceCount(&count);
    if (GPUavail != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("There is no GPU device available\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cudaGetDeviceProperties(prop, device);
    printf("Device name: %s\n", prop->name);
    printf("Global memory: %zd\n", prop->totalGlobalMem);
    printf("Shared memory: %zd\n", prop->sharedMemPerBlock);
    printf("Max threads per block: %d\n", prop->maxThreadsPerBlock);
    printf("Device ID: %d\n", prop->pciDeviceID);
    printf("TCC Driver: %d\n", prop->tccDriver);

    a = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    b = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    c = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc(&d_a, SIZE*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&d_b, SIZE*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&d_c, SIZE*sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i;
        c[i] = 0;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_c, c, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    VectorAdd << < 1, SIZE >> >(d_a, d_b, d_c, SIZE);

    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printResult(c);

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);
}
```

Source from: https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-c-cpp

And this is the displayed result:
[image]

Comment: Make SIZE 512 and try again. Then look again at everything you posted and also yourself why it works

Comment: Please show text messages as text, not as graphics. They are text, not painted artwork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GPU can only launch upto 512 threads per block, as it says in your program's output. (`Max threads per block`) However, you are launching 1024 threads in a block. Because you launched your kernel with invalid launch configuration, your kernel didn't launch at all. You should change the number of threads in the block.

```
#define SIZE 512
```

The threads per block limit is 1024 for compute capability >= 2.0, but your GPU is compute capability 1.0.

Comment: such a small error that I didn't find out, It now works for me.